# Microsoft graph - outlook mail - list all mail folders (not just the top level ones)?

Tags: api, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Currently, as far as I can tell, Microsoft graph offers 2 primary endpoints for outlook mail folders according to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message

`List mail folders` and `List child folders` - meaning just to build the folder hierarchy in my dashboard app, I need to make recursive REST API calls - which is very slow and very bad.

Is there any way to get microsoft to just return all folders at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. You should check the `childFolderCount` property on each folder and only query if non-zero.

Comment: Yes, but this goes back to the same problem of being extremely expensive and unpractical when factoring in network load times. Ive also tried using Imap4's list command with outlook - but cant seem to get oauth2 to work properly with microsoft graph. Is it possible to connect to outlook.com via oauth2 w/ graph or no?

Comment: Yes you can connect to outlook.com accounts with Graph. You need to use the Azure v2 app model OAuth implementation to be able to sign in and auth outlook.com accounts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code

Comment: You misunderstand me, I meant is it possible to connect to outlook.com with imap4 using oauth2 via microsoft graph?

Comment: No.Graph is a REST API, why would it connect with imap? :)

Comment: As a member of Microsoft, could you maybe bring this up? This is a pretty huge honking problem.

Comment: Sure, but it's better if you post it as a suggestion here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/. :)

Answer (score 9):

### Using the current V1.0

You can get two levels per call by expanding the childFolders container.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders?$top=250&$expand=childFolders
```

---

### Using the Beta Version

You can fetch up to 250 folders per request, you'll receive a flattened hierarchy which includes unlimited child levels. The beta version has been in beta since 2015 (best I can tell) and I cannot say when/if it will move to production. In my case I use the beta for fetching folders and fallback to v1.0 and recursive looping.

Simply change your GET request slightly. **v1.0**  *to*  **beta**. For me, the existing Auth tokens and credentials all work without any changes. Also note, there is no need to expand the childFolders using the Beta endpoint.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders?$top=250
```

*Example Response...*

```js
[{
    "id": "xx-1",
    "displayName": "Inbox",
    "parentFolderId": "xx-0",
    "childFolderCount": 1,
    "unreadItemCount": 8,
    "totalItemCount": 22,
    "wellKnownName": "inbox"
  },
  {
    "id": "xx-2",
    "displayName": "Level 2",
    "parentFolderId": "xx-1",
    "childFolderCount": 1,
    "unreadItemCount": 2,
    "totalItemCount": 4,
    "wellKnownName": null
  },
  {
    "id": "xx-3",
    "displayName": "level 3",
    "parentFolderId": "xx-2",
    "childFolderCount": 1,
    "unreadItemCount": 0,
    "totalItemCount": 0,
    "wellKnownName": null
  },
  {
    "id": "xx-4",
    "displayName": "level 4",
    "parentFolderId": "xx-3",
    "childFolderCount": 0,
    "unreadItemCount": 0,
    "totalItemCount": 0,
    "wellKnownName": null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can. Simply use delta query to get all the folders.

Request Example:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[user_id]/mailfolders/delta?$select=displayname](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%5Buser_id%5D/mailfolders/delta?$select=displayname)
You get an array of all the folders, with child folders just after the parent-folder item in the response.

Test:
Go to : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
GET Version: v1.0 URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/Mailfolders/delta
Run Query

Notice "Internal Screens" and "Project Falcon" folders whose parentFolderId is the ID of "Inbox" are also included in the response.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all mail folder lists in Microsoft graph API using CURL

```
$curl = curl_init();
$accessToken = ""; //Get the access token from your database or txt file
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/?includeHiddenFolders=true',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer '
  ),
 ));
   $response = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   echo $response;
```