# Microsoft Graph API : Is it possible to traverse recursive over Folders

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

We are converting from mail EWS into Microsoft office 365 Graph API,

I want to flat all my Folder tree into list of flat folders, so each entry in list should contain:

`Folder:{parentId, myId} , ...`

I saw in beta version there is an option to traverse with :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders/inbox?$top=50&$expand=childFolders($levels=5)
```

but unfortunately I get only the first Level...

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('4ed9f9bf-cfea-47de-ba2c-e4323d2dd600')/mailFolders/$entity",
    "id": "AQMkAGM5MDIzODk0LTg2NgBjLTQxN2EtOTNmMC0wYWY4M2VkMTg1MWEALgAAAxfTs4ItP_BBtfaokkhWqiMBAJ1RfNBJd7VOqHUq_F8aPdIAAAIBDQAAAA==",
    "displayName": "Inbox",
    "parentFolderId": "AQMkAGM5MDIzODk0LTg2NgBjLTQxN2EtOTNmMC0wYWY4M2VkMTg1MWEALgAAAxfTs4ItP_BBtfaokkhWqiMBAJ1RfNBJd7VOqHUq_F8aPdIAAAIBCQAAAA==",
    "childFolderCount": 1,
    "unreadItemCount": 307,
    "totalItemCount": 320,
    "wellKnownName": "inbox",
    "childFolders@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('4ed9f9bf-cfea-47de-ba2c-e4323d2dd600')/mailFolders('AQMkAGM5MDIzODk0LTg2NgBjLTQxN2EtOTNmMC0wYWY4M2VkMTg1MWEALgAAAxfTs4ItP_BBtfaokkhWqiMBAJ1RfNBJd7VOqHUq_F8aPdIAAAIBDQAAAA%3D%3D')/childFolders",
    "childFolders": [
        {
            "id": "AAMkAGM5MDIzODk0LTg2NmMtNDE3YS05M2YwLTBhZjgzZWQxODUxYQAuAAAAAAAX07OCLT-gQbX2qJJIVqojAQCdUXzQSXe1Tqh1KvhfGj3SAAOojCnvAAA=",
            "displayName": "LEVEL_1",
            "parentFolderId": "AQMkAGM5MDIzODk0LTg2NgBjLTQxN2EtOTNmMC0wYWY4M2VkMTg1MWEALgAAAxfTs4ItP_BBtfaokkhWqiMBAJ1RfNBJd7VOqHUq_F8aPdIAAAIBDQAAAA==",
            "childFolderCount": 1,
            "unreadItemCount": 0,
            "totalItemCount": 0,
            "wellKnownName": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a good API either with O-Data or maybe other traversal algorithm (like in EWS - Deep traversal ) , so I can reduce my rest API calls ...

Thanks =]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a deep folder traversal call in the Microsoft Graph API. You will need to expand each level. You may want to open a [feature request](https://aka.ms/graphrequests) for this.

With that said, you could use the [batch feature](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json-batching) to reduce the number of calls you have to make to get the folder hierarchy. You could have a single batch call to get all folders at **a given level** across hierarchies as long as the folder hierarchy isn't wider than 20 folders at any level (see [batch restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#json-batching)). You'd want to account for more than 20 folders at any level.

With regards to an algorithm to do this, I haven't seen this scenario so you might be originator of the Microsoft Graph deep folder traversal with batching algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it still relevant nowadays ? Can I keep track if new folder was created by delta query on root folder, if folder was created on 2-3rd levels ?

Comment: @DmytroSh. Yes, deep folder traversal is still not a thing. If you mean the mailbox root folder, Graph doesn't give access to that folder. If you mean the next level **default** folders in message sub-tree, like inbox, sent item, drafts, etc, you can use [DQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-messages?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0), but I doubt that it will discover **deep** changes. I hope it discovers changes changes to childFolderCount. I highly suggest you test it to see if that will work.

Comment: Links are death

Comment: Links have been fixed. Links are life. @LucaZiegler

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer in a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901755/microsoft-graph-outlook-mail-list-all-mail-folders-not-just-the-top-level-o/64101654#64101654) and it is in my opinion the easiest way to retrieve all mail folders and subfolders recursiveley in a flat list.

> Yes, you can. Simply use delta query to get all the folders.
>
> Request Example: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[user_id]/mailfolders/delta?$select=displayname` You get an array of all the folders, with child folders just after the parent-folder item in the response.
>
> Test:
> Go to : `https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer`
> GET Version: v1.0 URL: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/Mailfolders/delta`
> Run Query
>
> Notice "Internal Screens" and "Project Falcon" folders whose parentFolderId is the ID of "Inbox" are also included in the response.